# Missing "Connection Upgrade" Header When Trying To Use Signalr Core

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, http-headers, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm creating an application with a java/kotlin client app and a .Net Core based server running on aws elastic beanstalk. I am trying to implement real-time notifications using the Signalr Core library but have been having some issues. It seems whenever I attempt to make a connection between the client and server, the handshake fails while attempting to upgrade to websockets.

> Java Error: WebSocket closed from an error: Expected 'Connection' header value 'Upgrade' but was 'null'.

It seems that my response from the server is correct in everything except that the header "Connection":"Upgrade" is missing and causing my code to fail. I have looked extensively into this but have had no success with anything.

My server is running on a "Window Server 2016 Datacenter" instance using IIS 10 and Net Core 2.2.

My Code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSignalR(options =>
        {
            options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }

        app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
        {
               DefaultFileNames = new
               List<string> { "index.html" }
        });



        app.Use(async (context, nextMiddleWare) =>
        {
            context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
            {
                if (!context.Response.Headers.Keys.Contains("Connection"))
                {
                    context.Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "Upgrade");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Headers["Connection"] = "Upgrade";
                }

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });

            await nextMiddleWare();

            context.Response.OnCompleted(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LOG: Hitting Custom Middleware with status code: {0}", context.Response.StatusCode);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            });
            ;
        });

        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {

            routes.MapHub<MainHub>("/mainHub");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
```

...

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SetEbConfig();

        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

    private static void SetEbConfig()
    {
        var tempConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        tempConfigBuilder.AddJsonFile(
            @"C:\Program Files\Amazon\ElasticBeanstalk\config\containerconfiguration",
            optional: true,
            reloadOnChange: true
        );

        var configuration = tempConfigBuilder.Build();

        var ebEnv =
            configuration.GetSection("iis:env")
                .GetChildren()
                .Select(pair => pair.Value.Split(new[] { '=' }, 2))
                .ToDictionary(keypair => keypair[0], keypair => keypair[1]);

        foreach (var keyVal in ebEnv)
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(keyVal.Key, keyVal.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
 public class MainHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {

        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }

    public async Task BroadcastOrder(string groupName, Order order)
    {
        await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("New Order", order);
    }
    public  Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {

        return Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public Task LeaveGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

As you can see in Startup.cs, I even tried to manually add the header into the response using middleware, yet the header still wouldn't appear in my client. I may not fully understand how the middleware pipeline works (as I am fairly new to most of this) or other factors may be at play.

Comment: It's very likely you need to setup AWS to allow websockets. Here's a blog post about it https://anandhub.wordpress.com/2016/10/06/websocket-ebs/

Comment: @Brennan I don't have a load balancer set up yet since its still small and in development, thus I don't think the above link would apply. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You might need to configure IIS itself to allow websockets, I don't think it's on by default. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support#step-by-step-instructions

Comment: @Samuraiknight47 Did you ever solve this? I'm facing the exact same issue. It must be IIS related, as I have one server where it happens, and one where it doesn't. Also, the one that doesn't work sets a Transfer-Encoding: chunked header.